# Emacs doesn't start

Tags: macos, emacs

For quite a while now I have an irritating problem with functionality of my MacBook Pro 13’'

It culminated recently when I tried to make Emacs run smoothly (not in the first time) on my Mac. It doesn’t start always. After I initiate the start by clicking its icon on the doc it usually doesn’t. Just the word ‘Emacs’ appears at the top of the screen where the menu is but the app itself hangs indefinitely remaining irresponsive to any commands. The only possible continuation is to force it to quit. Then it unpredictably starts successfully and almost instantly and works fine. I use the latest versions of everything involved including Emacs and Mac OS X Yosemite (see below).

There’s no system or regularity. Some faulty (up to ten) attempts and one successful or vice versa.

Recently I tried starting Emacs under Guest account. It starts beautifully, always, and fast!

There’s no relevant or identifiable by me as relevant information in the log (console).

Having experienced problem for quite a while. It was present when I was using Mavericks (I upgrades to Yosemite).

Would you mind recommending some test, checking on files which could help to identify the problem?

Using:
http://emacsformacosx.com
Emacs For Mac OS X
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)

OS X Yosemite 10.10.1
MacBook Pro 13’’

MacBook Pro, OS X Yosemite (10.10.1)

Comment: Did you check contents of '.emacs' files in your account and in Guest accunt? '.emacs' file contains setup information and setup procedures.  New users of emacs like Guest start with almost empty .emacs files.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks! I check as soon as I can (I didn't take my Macbook with me). Guest's account .emacs files must be empty. I didn't edit / copy them. It doesn't help with my user account, I tried many times with empty .emacs file. Nevertheless, I check thoroughly when at home, thank you !

Comment: The easiest way to ensure that you aren't loading any configuration files is to invoke Emacs with `emacs -Q`. What exactly do you mean by "tried to make Emacs run smoothly on my Mac"? Emacs isn't a terribly demanding program...

Comment: I've seen this too. It occurs about 10% of the times I've started Emacs from the command line (even with -Q). I can't say if it have occurred when the application has been launched normally.

Comment: Thank you!
Pardon my poor English. 'run smoothy' meant make it start successfully.
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --no-init-file
does the job, alas! only occasionally.

Comment: I would say with -Q it starts more frequent than without. 
Effectively my .emacs is
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "~/quicklisp/ccl")

Comment: It occurred to me that Emacs debugging information could reveal something useful. So far I found no command line argument for that.

Comment: This used to happen to me too (second invocation would always work) until today, when now it hangs 100% of the time.  Yikes!

Comment: I had this problem today after some software update from Apple. I updated the wilder beast, started it with `-Q` from the terminal and now it works again. Not sure if we all have the same problem but this worked for me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The developers seem to have fixed it in the next version (25).  The last link on the page
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#macos
is a link to the binary
https://emacsformacosx.com/
that when installed started reliably from the command line (so far):

```
open -a Emacs
```

or

```
touch somefile.txt
open -a Emacs somefile.txt
```

I like to include

```
alias acs='open -a Emacs'
```

in my ~/.profile so I can just type

```
acs somefile.txt
```